# Why do I get InvalidSignatureException Error when invoking AWS Lambda with LambdaClient from @aws-sdk/client-lambda but it worked on older aws-sdk?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

right now I am in a situation where I am getting this error:

```
InvalidSignatureException: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

when invoking Lambda from `@aws-sdk/client-lambda` altough it worked with `aws-sdk`

My previous code which worked well:

```
import Lambda from 'aws-sdk/clients/lambda';

async function sendDataFromMiroToDBFunction(){
        
        const data = await miro.board.select();
        
        const accessKey = 'MyAccessKey';
        const secretAccess = 'MySecretKey';
        
        const lambda = new Lambda({
            accessKeyId: accessKey,
            secretAccessKey: secretAccess,
            region: 'eu-central-1'
        });
    
        const params = {
        FunctionName: 'vx4AppSync2DynamoLambda-staging',
        Payload: JSON.stringify({Data: data})
        };

        lambda.invoke(params, function(err: any, data: any) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else     console.log(data);
        });   

        

    }
```

However because I am using vite and I also have limited memory on aws and this aws-sdk was always bigger than 500KiB, I had to reduce the size of the chunks by importing specifically only lambda not the whole aws-sdk, like this:

```
import { LambdaClient, InvokeCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-lambda";

async function sendDataFromMiroToDBFunction(){
        
        const data = await miro.board.select(); //Sice to hází error, ale funguje
        
        const accessKey = 'MyAccessKey';
        const secretAccess = 'MySecretAccess';
    
        const client = new LambdaClient({
            credentials: {
                accessKeyId: accessKey,
                secretAccessKey: secretAccess,
            },
            region: 'eu-central-1',
        });
        const input = { // InvocationRequest
            FunctionName: 'vx4AppSync2DynamoLambda-staging', // required
            Payload: data,
        };
        const command = new InvokeCommand(input);
        const response = await client.send(command);
        

    }
```

And this solution is now throwing me the error mentioned above and I am asking why, when credentials are still the same.. I am really frustrated by it right now.

My package.json looks like that:

```
{
  "name": "drag-and-drop",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mirohq/websdk-types": "latest",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.33",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.0.7",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "vite": "^3.1.0",
    "vite-plugin-chunk-split": "^0.4.7",
    "vite-plugin-node-polyfills": "^0.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "^5.2.3",
    "@aws-sdk/client-lambda": "^3.310.0",
    "@aws-sdk/types": "^3.310.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-dynamic-import-vars": "^2.0.3",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.0.18",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1340.0",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "openai": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.58.3"
  }
}
```

Thank you for any help.